# Django custom queryset with pre-filter

Tags: django, django-managers

Is there a way in django to write a custom queryset class that has a filter "pre-applied" without having to call a method on it?

I want to create a manager using `QuerySet.as_manager()`. But I want that manager to automatically filter out some entries.

Answer (score 0):

**Django offer you two way to write customs manager for your models**.
The first is called like this : `MyModel.objects.my_manager()`.
The last is called like this : `MyModel.my_manager.all()`.

I'll show you the last one, since it's simple to achieve.

Let's suppose this models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Yur custom manager.
```

Now to have a manager that return only `published` Post :

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset()\
        .filter(published=True)
```

From here, you are able to do queryset like this :
`published_posts = Post.published.all()`
Or apply some filter on it like :
`published_posts = Post.published.all().order_by('-title')`

**NB :** The manager definition come before the Post model.

For the another way to deal with manager [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to achieve the DRY benefits of creating a manager from a custom queryset, so that your manager and queryset can easily have the same methods for chaining. But I also want to be able to pre-filter like you can with `get_queryset()`. Does that make sense?

Comment: hey @samfrances, are you trying to do something like `CustomManager.from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)` but the custom `get_queryset()` method never gets called?